# Using NewRelic monitor of Django Channels/asyncio/asgi

Tags: python, django, django-channels, newrelic, asgi

NewRelic doesn't have a documented example of how to monitor a Django Channels application.  Mostly concern about monitoring the eventloop, using the methods provided [here](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/apm/agents/python-agent/python-agent-api/asgiapplication-python-agent-api/) don't seem to work as ProtocolRouter in Channels is the "application" and seems layers deep since we are running Gunicorn with Uvicorn workers.

Love to see someone who has implemented this.